# Are reads or select a, b, c queries faster in the Cosmos DB Java API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

My partition key is "id", so each item has its own partition.

Which of the following is more performant?

1. Calling container.read(id, new PartitionKey(id)) and then manually filtering out the results in a Java forloop to only show fields a, b, and c.
2. Calling a SQL query "SELECT a, b, c FROM c WHERE c.id = @id".

The only reason I'd think the second one is slower is because it has to parse a query, but I'm not sure what optimizations are done on the "SELECT a, b, c" part that I'm missing out on in the first one.

Which one is faster?

Comment: There's really no exact way to answer this. While point-reads (when you know both id and partition key value) cost less than an equivalent query in terms of Request Units (RU), you might have to contend with additional bandwidth (for very large documents e.g. 1-2MB). You'd need to benchmark this (as mentioned in another comment), as well as benchmarking your Java code (though I suspect the difference will be negligible on the Java side).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/optimize-cost-queries

Comment: What do you mean by "filtering out the results in a Java forloop to only show fields a, b, and c."    There will be only one item returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read() will always be faster than a query for the same row and requires fewer RU/s because read() bypasses our query engine entirely and talks directly to our storage layer.

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Mark!